# Correspondence between r-dim subspaces of finite fields $F^n$ and $r \times n$ rref matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

[image]

Using the hint, I'm thinking the answer to question 1 should be $9^2$, and question 2 $9^5$, since we want to find the number of matrices of the following forms:

$$\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
    1 & . & . \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$

and

$$\left[ 
\begin{matrix}
    1 & . & . & .\\
    0 & 1 & . & .
    \end{matrix}
\right]$$

for questions 1 and 2, respectively. There would be $9^2$ ways to fill in the blanks in the first matrix, and $9^5$ in the second matrix, using the 9 elements of the field.

But I'm not sure about this. Could anyone verify?

Also, for question 3, am I again asked for the number of those $r \times n$ matrices?

Answer (score 1):

(1) Let us use $q=9$ for the number of elements in the given field $F$.
Let now $V$ be a $1$-dimensional subspace of $F^3$. We pick an element $b\ne 0$ in $V$, the system with the only one element $\{b\}$ is a basis for $V$. The number of such choices of a $b\ne 0$ is $q^3-1$. Two choices $b$, and $b'$ are generating the same space, iff they differ by multiplication with a non-zero scalar. There are $q-1$ such scalars. So the number of $1$-dimensional subspaces of $V=F^3$ is
$$
\frac{q^3-1}{q-1}\ .
$$
**Alternatively**, we can use the given result, so need to count "reduced echelon matrices", REM for short in the sequel. This counting may look as follows in this particular case. Let
$$A=[\ a_{11}\ a_{12}\ a_{13}\ ]
$$
be such an REM.

- If $a_{11}=1$, then we have free choices for the other two entries, so there are $q^2$ choices of $A$ matching the pattern $[1**]$.
- Else, $a_{11}=0$, so we go deeper in the row:

  - If $a_{12}=1$, then we have a free choice for the other entry, so there are $q$ choices of $A$ matching the pattern $[0\ 1\ *]$.
  - Else $a_{12}=0$, so we go deeper again.

    - Only the one choice $[\ 0\ 0\ 1]$ remains.

So there are $$q^2+q+1$$ vector subspaces of $V$, same answer.

---

(2) Same game, two ways to count. Let $W=F^4$, $F=\Bbb F_q$ being a field with $q$ elements. We choose a basis $b_1,b_2$ of $W$. For $b_1\ne 0$ we have $(q^4-1)$ choices. For each such choice, there are $q$ vectors which are linearly dependent w.r.t $b_1$, all scalar multiples of $b_1$, $b_2$ must avoid them, so that we get a linearly independent system, so there are $(q^4-q)$ choices for $b_2$.

Two such choices $(b_1, b_2)$, and $(b_1',b_2')$ are generating the same two-dimensional space, iff there is a base change, so iff we can **formally write**
$$
\underbrace{
\begin{bmatrix}
s_{11} & s_{12}\\
s_{21} & s_{22}\\
\end{bmatrix}}_{:=S}
\begin{bmatrix}
b_1\\b_2
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
b'_1\\b'_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with an invertible $2\times 2$-matrix $S$ with entries in $F$.
How many choices are there for $S$?

For its first column there are $q^2-1$ possibilities.

After each choice of the first column, there are for its second column exactly $q^2-q$ possibilities, so that there is not linear dependency.

Putting all together, we see that there are 
$$
\frac{(q^4-1)(q^4-q)}{(q^2-1)(q^2-q)}
$$
vector subspaces of dimension two inside $W=\Bbb F_q^4$.

**Alternatively**, we can use the given result, so need to count the REM's of shape $2\times 4$.
$$
A
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}& a_{12}& a_{13} &a_{14}\\
a_{21}& a_{22}& a_{23} &a_{24}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
be such an REM. 
Things get now combinatorial, and less structural if we "must use" the result. The following shapes occur:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & * & * \\
0 & 1 & * & *
\end{bmatrix}
&\qquad\text{there are $q^2\cdot q^2$ possibilities,}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & * & 0 & * \\
0 & 0 & 1 & *
\end{bmatrix}
&\qquad\text{there are $q^2\cdot q$ possibilities,}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & * & * & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\qquad\text{there are $q^2\cdot 1$ possibilities.}
\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{So for this type $a_{11}=1$ there are totally $q^2\cdot (q^2+q+1)$ possibilities,}
\\[2mm]
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & * \\
0 & 0 & 1 & *
\end{bmatrix}
&\qquad\text{there are $q\cdot q$ possibilities,}
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & * & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
&\qquad\text{there are $q\cdot 1$ possibilities,}
\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{So for this type $a_{11}=a_{21}=0$, $a_{12}=1$ there are totally $q\cdot (q+1)$ possibilities,}
\\[2mm]
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\\
&\qquad\text{$1\cdot 1$ last possibility.}
\end{aligned}
$$
Totally, we get $q^2(q^2+q+1)+(q^2+q)+1=q^2(q^2+q+1)+(q^2+q+1)=\dots$
$$
(q^2+1)(q^2+q+1)
$$
possibilities, same result.

---

(3)

- The vector $v_1\ne 0$ has $q^n$ possibilities. The are $q$ possible linear combination of the system $\{v_1\}$, namely $a_1v_1$, and we have $q$ choices for $a_1$.
- The vector $v_2$ has then $q^n-q$ possibilities, so that the system $\{v_1,v_2\}$ is linearly independent, $v_2$ has to avoid the linear combinations above. The are now $q^2$ possible linear combination of the system $\{v_1,v_2\}$, namely $a_1v_1+a_2v2$, since we have $q$ choices for $a_1$, and $q$ choices for $a_2$.
- The vector $v_3$ has then $q^n-q^2$ possibilities, so that the system $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is linearly independent, $v_3$ has to avoid the linear combinations above. The are now $q^3$ possible linear combination of the system $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$, namely $a_1v_1+a_2v2+a_3v_3$, since we have $q$ choices for each $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$.

This goes systematically further.
So the number of linearly independent tuples is
$$
(q^n-q^0)
(q^n-q^1)
(q^n-q^2)
\dots
(q^n-q^{r-1})
\ .
$$